# redirecting a reactive form in angular after submitting

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, router

I am trying to redirect to another page (called landing) after the user submits the form in my angular app, i have done the following code in the reg-form.page.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { NavController, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TermsComponent } from '../reg-form/terms/terms.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from '../reg-form/privacy/privacy.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-reg-form',
templateUrl: './reg-form.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./reg-form.page.scss'],
})
export class RegFormPage implements OnInit {
form: FormGroup;
router: any;

constructor(
private modalCtrl: ModalController,  private http: HttpClient, public fb: FormBuilder)  
{this.form = this.fb.group({
firstname: [''],
lastname: [''],
})}

ngOnInit() {
this.form = new FormGroup({
  firstname: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  }),
  lastname: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  }),
 }

onSubmitForm () {
var formData: any = new FormData();
formData.append("firstname", this.form.get('firstname').value);
formData.append("lastname", this.form.get('lastname').value);


this.http.post('https://mywebsite/.../,,,,/app-registrationForm.php', formData,   
{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
  (response) => console.log(response),
  (error) => console.log(error)
);

this.form.reset();
this.router.navigate(['/landing']);
```

and have tried using the router.navigate at the bottom but it doesn't navigate to the landing page. Should I be including something else? Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to the landing page only after he successfully logins, then you need to write the router logic inside response:

Also router.navigate expects an array of routes, so split and send the route.

```
this.http.post('https://mywebsite/.../,,,,/app-registrationForm.php', formData,   
{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
  (response) => { 
     console.log(response);
     this.router.navigate(['/', 'landing']);
  },
  (error) => console.log(error)
);
```